# C++ passing dynamic method pointer as a method argument of different class

Tags: c++, class, oop, function-pointers

I'm making an allegro game in which button class should be independent so I'm putting function pointer inside of button object for OnClick event. Progressing through the project I've been putting global function in the argument of MyButton constructor and everything was working - the problem appeared when I tried passing Node::OnClick() there:

Node.h:

```
class Node {
private:
    static int _id;
    int id;
    bool active;
    std::vector<Node*> neighbours;
    std::vector<bool> mask;
public:
    Node();
    int getId();
    void addNeighbour(Node* neighbour);
    void OnClick();
    void Check();
    void Uncheck();
    bool isActive();
};
```

MyButton.h:

```
class MyButton {
private:
    MyRectangle* boundingBox;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP* image;
    void (*onClick)(void);
public:
    MyButton();
    MyButton(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* img, MyRectangle* boundingBox, void (*onClick)(void)); 
    MyButton(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* img, int x, int y, void (*onClick)(void)); 
    void Draw();
    void clickCheck(int x, int y);
};
```

main:

```
Node* current = graph->getNode(i);
buttons[i] = new MyButton(scarab1, button_coords[0]-27, button_coords[1]-27, current->OnClick);
```

ERROR:

```
error C3867: 'Node::OnClick': function call missing argument list; use '&Node::OnClick' to create a pointer to member
```

this code executes just fine:

```
buttons[i] = new MyButton(scarab1, button_coords[0]-27, button_coords[1]-27, &testOnClick);
```

once i put &Node::OnClick into ctor argument like this:

```
buttons[i] = new MyButton(scarab1, button_coords[0]-27, button_coords[1]-27, &Node::OnClick);
```

then i'm getting:

```
main.cpp(135): error C2664: 'MyButton::MyButton(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *,int,int,void (__cdecl *)(void))' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'void (__thiscall Node::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2.html). It already implements all of the signal/slot processing for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Node::OnClick` function is of type `void (Node::*)(void)`.

You may want to look into using [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). (Or [`mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) depending on what's available to you. `mem_fun` is deprecated and has been replaced by `mem_fn`)

`mem_fn(&Node::OnClick)` will return a function pointer of type `void (*)(void)` in this case. (The type is unspecified technically.)

Heck, at this point, I'd recommend forgetting function pointers all together and looking into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

---

Okay, the `std::function` alternative would be much cleaner here:

```
// Pass *current here
auto fn = std::bind(&Node::OnClick, class_instance);
```

The line above will return a callable object out of the member function tied to an instance of the class. Pass that to your function, but instead of a function pointer, use an `std::function<void(void)>`.

Comment: how do I incorporate an object into that pointer? Node::OnClick seems static

Comment: For that, `mem_fn(&Node::OnClick, *current);`

Comment: 1>main.cpp(136): error C2780: 'std::tr1::_Call_wrapper<std::tr1::_Callable_pmd<_Rx_Arg0::* const ,_Arg0,false>> std::tr1::mem_fn(_Rx _Arg0::* const )' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
1>          D:\VisualStudio\VC\include\functional(28) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::mem_fn'  It doesn't seem to be taking 2 arguments, what about std::function way for objects?

Comment: There you go, a much cleaner solution. Function pointers are only really needed when you profiled your application and found that the bottleneck is the invoking of the std::function objects stored. std::function usage is much cleaner.